# How to get a GridView's selected Id?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView that uses the select. I want to grab the RegistrantId of which row is selected. I've tried a bunch of ways and haven't had luck.

C#

```
  GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
        if ((row != null))
        {
            string registrantId = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            PnlEdit.Visible = true;
         }
```

I need to figure out what to put at `string registrantId =`. It needs to equal the value of the RegistrantId from that row.

This attempt above, for example, gives me a compile error for `RowIndex` stating that "EventArgs does not contain a definition for RowIndex."

Comment: Inside which event you have this code?

Comment: Page_Load `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){}`

Comment: No the `Page_Load` event's EventArgs will not have the `RowIndex` property, you need to write this code inside `RowSelecting` event as mentioned by @devlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the RowIndex like so:

```
string registrantId = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]
```

This assumes that you have the DataKeyNames property set in your gridview

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" DataKeyNames="RegistrantId" >
```

Also, if this method is triggered by an event handler, you might want to change your null check condition to:

```
protected void GridView1_RowSelecting(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
   var registrantId = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex];
   if(registrantId != null)
   {
       PnlEdit.Visible = true;
   }

}
```

(You know the row exists because it was selected and that selection is what causes the event to trigger.  The null check confirms you were able to obtain the registrantId from the row)

Comment: I see from your comment that you added to your question that you have this in Page_Load.  Your gridview doesn't have RowIndex until after Page_Load.  You should move your code to an event handler that's triggered by row selection, similar to what I've posted in my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! In my ASP GridView code, don't I have to reference `GridView1_RowSelecting` for it to work?

Comment: Yes.  You can do this with OnSelectedIndexChanged.  You should probably match your method name to the event (i.e.  GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged).  Your GridView property would be: `OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"`

Comment: I am sorry, I am still having issues with this EventArgs. So I have what you did but it still underlines RowIndex. `<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" DataKeyNames="RegistrantId" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
            AllowSorting="True"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceViewRegistrant">`

Comment: `protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var registrantId = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex];
        if (registrantId != null)
        {
            PnlEdit.Visible = true;
}`

Comment: If I use your delete one,i get the error `: No overload for 'GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'`

Comment: I had the wrong event handler in my example.  I've corrected that.  Are you using a select button, or just clicking  the row to trigger the event?

Comment: I am using the select button that GridView provides. When select is hit, GridView1_RowSelecting needs to happen.

Comment: OK, then you should be able to get the key using `var registrantId = GridView1.SelectedValue;`  See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onselectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)